# C# static field, instance constructor

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, static

I've come across a C# behavior that I would like to understand. Consider a class like this:

```
public class SomeSingleton
{
    public static SomeSingleton Default = new SomeSingleton();

    private static int field = 0;

    private SomeSingleton()
    {
        field = 1;
    }

    public int GetField()
    {
        return field;
    }
}
```

Now, let's call GetField() method:

```
var field = SomeSingleton.Default.GetField();
```

I am getting `0` as if the instance constructor was skipped. Why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just swap the order of `field` declaration before `Default`.

So your lines:

```
public static SomeSingleton Default = new SomeSingleton();
private static int field = 0;
```

should be:

```
private static int field = 0;
public static SomeSingleton Default = new SomeSingleton();
```

The reason is due to field initialization order. First `Default` is initialized in your code, which assigns `field` value of `1`. Later that field is assigned `0` in initialization. Hence you see the latest value of `0` and not `1`.

See: [10.4.5.1 Static field initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx)

> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a
>   sequence of assignments that are executed in the **textual order** in
>   which they appear in the class declaration.

Comment: Better yet, take out the initializer for `field` entirely.  All fields are preset to zero (or `null`) when the object is first created (for static fields, when the type is first loaded).

Answer (score 7):

This is because the ordering of the `static` variables. If you switch the two statements, the output becomes `1`:

```
private static int field = 0;

public static SomeSingleton Default = new SomeSingleton();
```

This is expected behavior as documented in [MSDN: Static field initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx).

See [this .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CL9pLF).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link to .NET Fiddle, brilliant tool.

Answer (score 3):

Switch the order of the static variables.

```
private static int field = 0;
public static SomeSingleton Default = new SomeSingleton();
```

In your code, the constructor runs first, which sets `field`, and then `field` overrides its value.